# How to copy a table into another table in the same word file using python?

Tags: python-3.x, docx, python-docx, docx-mailmerge

> Consider there are two tables in a MS docx file. First Table with X rows and Y columns and second table with M rows and N columns in the same MS docxfile. Now i want to copy complete second table along with its contents to one of cell (say cell (X,Y)) of first table in python. 
>   Example of table shown below:

[First Table with 2 columns 5 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiQnc.png)
[Second Table with 3 columns 4 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDFLh.png)

> Now i want to copy second table full content with formatting into last cell of the first table. Final result after copy should look like below:

[Result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR8SE.png)

> How do we achieve this in python ?

Comment: May I request what have you tried? Any piece of codes?

Answer (score 0):

From [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/docx-mailmerge/): Merge table rows. In your template, add a MergeField to the row you would like to designate as template. Supply the name of this MergeField as anchor parameter. The second parameter contains the rows with key-value pairs for the MergeField replacements.

```
document.merge_rows('col1',
                    [{'col1': 'Row 1, Column 1', 'col2': 'Row 1 Column 1'},
                     {'col1': 'Row 2, Column 1', 'col2': 'Row 2 Column 1'},
                     {'col1': 'Row 3, Column 1', 'col2': 'Row 3 Column 1'}])
```